# How work with two models and one form?

Tags: python, django

I've got two models ('Student', 'Instructor') and one form 'RegisterForm' with two selectors (for types). How can i save data from form in corresponding model if in class Meta field 'model' just for the only one model? 
I guess, my way is wrong, but so i asking.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()
    passed_tests = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    available_tests = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class Instructor(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()
    written_tests = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case You can use relationships. For example try ForeignKey(relation one to many) od ManyToMany(relation many to many).